# Does "I saw a blue car and bus" mean "blue bus" or any coloured bus?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, nouns, british-english, conjunctions

What is the outcome of any and every sentence in the following sentence format when the rules of English grammar is applied upon them.

sentence format <Noun Verb Determiner Adjective Noun Conjunction Noun.

Will the sentence in the said sentence format be interpreted as <Noun Verb Determiner Adjective (Noun Conjunction Noun)> or will it be interpreted as <Noun Verb Determiner (Adjective Noun) Conjunction Noun> ?

For example: -
Does this sentence "I saw a blue car and bus" mean "blue bus" or any coloured bus ?

Tks

Comment: I think most people would understand it to mean that both were blue, unless you said "a blue car and **a** bus".

Comment: Without further context,It's a bit ambiguous.

Comment: Can you make this problem more real?  Do you often talk with people about the colours of cars and buses.  Do you need to use this sentence in a real conversation.  I think you want to ask about a general point,  but what is the specific problem that you face?

Comment: The sentence is not really idiomatic, not something a native speaker is likely to say.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One Noun, Two Adjectives, Connected with "and"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/184021/one-noun-two-adjectives-connected-with-and)

Comment: I am trying to understand the rules of English grammar and what will be the outcome after applying the rules of English grammar upon the said sentence "I saw a blue car and bus". I also want to understand the rules of English grammar relating to noun, adjective, determiner and conjunction (and their precedence relationships). please can someone explain the said rules.

Comment: A duplicate of [Does an adjective or longer modifier apply to both nouns when they are joined with 'and' or 'or'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/130207/does-an-adjective-or-longer-modifier-apply-to-both-nouns-when-they-are-joined-wi) (and others).

Comment: What if you asked for "a cold beer and chips" at a restaurant? Do you expect the chips to be cold?

Comment: My wheelie (garbage/rubbish) bin has embossed on the lid: "No hot ashes or liquid" - am I allowed to put cold liquid into it? (I doubt they would want that to be honest).

Comment: English is **extremely ambiguous almost all the time**. Grammar is **irrelevant** to ambiguity.

Comment: Try comparing that to 'I saw a flying aircraft and ship'. Strictly, 'a blue car and bus' is incomplete and therefore wrong.

The Question at first glance sounds wholly reasonable, but in fact the chance of any native speaker saying anything like that is so slight, you should rule it out… in fact, you take it as an example of the exception that proves the rule.

Comment: I'm surprised by the upvoted comments claiming that native English speakers would never/rarely say such a thing.  I hear native English speakers speak with this type of ambiguous language frequently.  A friend of mine makes a living as a professional editor.  Her specialty is editing PhD theses written in English, typically written by native speakers.  She states she has to frequently fix this type of error.  Is it ambiguous?  *Yes.*  It it confusing? *Often.*  Is it common?  In my experience (and that of my friend)? *Yes.*

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Define ‘this type’. The particular example given in the question sounds strange and is unlikely to be said by a native speaker. The example given in Nick Gammon’s comment above is perfectly normal and idiomatic (and yes, ambiguous). The oddness of the example given is not down to the syntactic structure of the sentence so much as the specific words used and how they might relate to each other. Similarly, “She was wearing a blue skirt and sneakers” is fine; “She was wearing a blue skirt and backpack” is strange (we’d expect ‘and _a_ backpack’).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: I'd take "She was wearing a blue skirt and backpack". The implication to me is either that she has colour-coordinated her clothes with her luggage, or anyway that the speaker is remarking on the similarity of colour. I wouldn't say it just to save a syllable, though, as some answers have suggested. I'd say it only to link the colour of the skirt with the colour of the backpack.

Comment: @RockPaperLz: I think when people say, "native speakers wouldn't say this" they don't mean it literally. Especially so for writing rather than speech. Usually they mean, "if a native speaker said this and was corrected, on the whole they'd accept it's an error". For example, if I frequently type "teh" for "the", but I thank my spell-checker or my editor for correcting it, then "teh" is not idiolectic even though it is frequent. If I furiously write STET over the correction, and so do many native speakers, because we're intentionally doing internet-speak, that's idiomatic :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks Steve.  Your explanation may not be obvious to the OP, or others, so I'm glad you wrote it for all to read.

Comment: @Stechavy you have received such varied opinions on if the bus is blue across all the answers and comments that this question has fairly conclusively been answered as “your sentence has inherent ambiguity despite being grammatically correct”. Roughly half the people who have interacted with this question fall on each side. If the bus is blue, say *a blue car and a blue bus* or *a car and a bus, both of which were blue.*

Answer (score 13):

As commented, OP's example is a bit "weird". But here are two different versions of a common assertion that manifests the same potential ambiguity, showing how native Anglophones resolve that ambiguity...

> 1: *I have a younger brother and sister*
> (very strongly implies my brother *and* sister are ***both*** younger than me)
> 2: *I have a younger brother and **a** sister* <sup>1</sup>
> (strongly implies ***only my brother*** is younger)

> ...and for completeness...
> 3: *I have a sister and younger brother*
> 4: *I have a sister and a younger brother*
> ...both of which mean the same as #2 (only the brother is younger)

It's important to note that if the adjective modifies only *one* noun, we [normally specify the "unmodified" noun first](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=younger%20brother%20and%20a%20sister%2Csister%20and%20younger%20brother%2Csister%20and%20a%20younger%20brother&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10), so #2 isn't actually very common anyway...

[image]

As [this usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=younger%20brother%20and%20a%20sister%2Cyounger%20brother%20and%20sister%2Csister%20and%20younger%20brother%2Csister%20and%20a%20younger%20brother&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) shows, references to siblings who are *both* younger far outweigh references explicitly stating that only one sibling is younger. That's why I didn't include #1 in the chart (comparatively speaking, all other versions would just "flatline" on the chart).

---

<sup>1</sup> The effect of repeating the article here is to place more "syntactic distance" between the two nouns, which therefore makes it less likely that we would extend the scope of the adjective to apply to both. Exactly the same effect arises if we include a comma / pause before ***and***. Either or both of these "distancing" methods can be used to override the default assumption that the scope of the adjective *does* "run through" to the second noun.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What I am trying to understand is the precedence relationship between adjective and conjunction as per the rules of English grammar. In other words, if we were to design a robot which clearly understands the complete English grammar, then how will the robot interpret this sentence "I saw a blue car and bus". Will it interpret it as "I saw a blue (car and bus)", or will it interpret it as "I saw a (blue car) and bus" ?

Comment: Without other context, the robot had better regard this as ambiguous and not make any decisions based on either meaning. Perhaps its neural network can recognize that the color of the bus is uncertain, and there is an X% chance that it is blue. Of course, there's a less-than-100% chance the *car* is blue, though a 100% chance that the speaker said so...

Comment: As people keep pointing out, your example is "weird", so it's not easy for native Anglophones to give a sensible summary of how they would interpret it. But the whole point of my answer is to show how the syntax works with a much more common situation. *I have a younger brother and sister* is syntactically identical to *I saw a blue car and van*, so we parse both utterances in the same way - *a blue (car and van) = a younger (brother and sister).*

Comment: @rcook: No - you *don't* need "context" to recognize that the default meaning of *a younger brother and sister* is ***two younger siblings***. If only the brother is younger, we're *far* more likely to say *a sister and [a] younger brother*. This becomes even more obvious in the plural, where no-one in his right mind would interpret ***I have younger brothers and sisters*** as implying that some or all of the sisters *aren't* younger than the speaker.

Comment: I am trying to understand the rules of English grammar and what will be the outcome after applying the rules of English grammar upon the said sentence "I saw a blue car and bus". I also want to understand the rules of English grammar relating to noun, adjective, determiner and conjunction (and their precedence relationships). please can someone explain the said rules.

Comment: @Stechavy: This isn't a "syntactic rule" - it's an *idiomatic tendency*. But because your particular example is a bit odd, people aren't clear on how that tendency applies. Look again at my text and charts, and you should see how strongly we prefer to specify the unmodified noun first, if there's a mix.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Umm...My idea is that why someone only give information about the colour of one thing(of car) why not about the bus, He might have given information(of colour) about the bus. (This is my doubt).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think He deliberately didn't mention it because the colour of car is what he is trying to emphasize.

Comment: @Sam: It's completely irrelevant ***why*** someone might want to only specify the colour of one of two types of vehicle he reports seeing. All I'm saying is that *idiomatically*, when it comes to ***how*** to express it, we normally specify the ***unmodified*** noun first. That's why *I have a younger brother and sister* would be a "peculiar" way of saying it if only the brother was younger.

Comment: if by anyway my example is not clear, then please do not consider that. Instead consider the sentence format. if a sentence is the following format, then what would be the outcome applying rules of English grammar. Sentence Format: - <Noun Verb Determiner Adjective Noun Conjunction Noun>.

Comment: @Stechavy: I *haven't* considered your example, except to point out that it's a bit weird. I used my own example which involves perfectly natural situations (speaker want to assert that he has at least two siblings of different sexes, AND to unambiguously include the information that one or both of those siblings are younger than the speaker). What is it you don't understand? Please modify the question text, rather than add clarification in comments.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I concur with you, but why someone wants to confuse others by saying airily.

Comment: I have already told what I want to know. All I want to know is, what would be the outcome of ANY and EVERY sentence in the following sentence format, when the rules of English grammar is applied to the sentence. Sentence Format: <Noun Verb Determiner Adjective Noun Conjunction Noun>. Should the sentence be interpreted as <Noun Verb Determiner Adjective (Noun Conjunction Noun)> or should it be interpreted as <Noun Verb Determiner (Adjective Noun) Conjunction Noun>. If you want me to edit the question, I am happy to edit the question.

Comment: @Stechavy: For the umpteenth time, ***it's not a rule***. I've told you the default principles, but you can see from comments under James's answer that native speakers can easily find examples that don't reflect the convention - either forcing us to *reverse* the normal principle, OR to accept that some statements are inherently ambiguous. If the ambiguity is a problem, just rephrase.

Comment: Isn't your usage chart confounded by phrases like "older sister and younger brother" that would give a match for "sister and younger brother"? That is, for #3 and #4, you haven't actually constrained "sister" to be unmodified.

Comment: @nanoman: Good catch - the chart's certainly *affected* by ***older** sister and [a] younger brother*. But [here's the quantification](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=older+sister+and+younger+brother%2Csister+and+younger+brother%2Csister+and+a+younger+brother&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=10) for the version *not* repeating the article (can't do the other one, 'cos it's too many words). Contexts explicitly mentioning *older* sister account for under half the chart. What's left still dwarfs the "unidiomatic" version at the bottom of the chart.

Comment: While this answer is as such a fantastic essay about related issues. It simply doesn't explain, answer, the core of the question.

Comment: @Fattie: Okay, I'll bite. What exactly is "the core of the question" that you think I haven't addressed? It seems to me I've exhaustively covered OP's *Does this sentence "I saw a blue car and bus" mean "blue bus" or any coloured bus?* I've even explained *why* that's not a very idiomatic construction, having gone into detail about how we nearly always specify the *unmodified* noun first in such contexts, if an adjective only applies to one of two nouns linked by ***and***.

Comment: Fumble - sorry, i accidentally hit "send!!!"  The OP **thinks grammar relates to ambiguity**, the OP is asking "what's wrong with the grammar, how should the grammar be different".  Answer, grammar has no connection at all to ambiguity.  The sentence "I saw a blue car and bus" is 10000% AOK grammatically, end of story.

Comment: In other words *"What is the outcome of any and every sentence in the following sentence format when the rules of English grammar is applied upon them."* there is no "outcome" (no "meaning"). It's ubiquitous that sentences in English are highly ambiguous. Note that for me the sentence clearly means "[Next, ] I cut in half {ie, with a chainsaw} a bus and car."  There's no "outcome".

Comment: @Fattie: You're quite right, of course. Learners often perceive more ambiguity in English than the natives do, for obvious reasons, so we can't do much about that. But we *can* keep banging on about the difference between ***grammatically / syntactically valid*** and ***natural / idiomatic / easily understood***.

Comment: yes, that's true enough

Comment: The ngram is useful regarding writing. I don't think this point holds in standard, informal speech. Often you find yourself in stream of conscious explanation mode. "Don't you have a sister?" "Yeah, I have a younger sister, [micro pause, considering the other sibling may be of interest] and a brother." It's important not to be too normative about word order because often we assemble sentences on the fly.

Comment: It also makes me curious what speakers of languages with stricter word order (many other Germanic languages, Mandarin I think?) do in stream of consciousness. It seems like German and Dutch pivot around the verb in a way that facilitates this: "Gestern hab' ich...(pause) hab ich das und das gemacht." Not sure about that though.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive: I'd say it's almost certain that only a minority of all the texts matching my ngram search strings will be "informal speech" (whether "standard" or not). So they won't significantly affect any conclusions one might draw from those charts.

Comment: Right. That was my point. Probably should have added *but* after editing.

Comment: @CynicallyNaive: The OP's actual question was always a bit "iffy" (weird examples ***and*** an apparent reluctance to accept that there's no hard-and-fast syntactic rule that can be learned and followed here). But when it comes to actual *speech*, there wouldn't be much for learners to worry about anyway. If what they said was unclear or ambiguous, *and if the exact meaning mattered*, they'd probably be asked to clarify what they meant (and / or told how to more naturally express things).

Answer (score 5):

It means "a blue bus". After "and" you can omit repeated words. In this way:

- I saw a car and (a) bus
- I saw a blue car and (a blue) bus

Comment: …except I'm fairly certain that no native English speaker would ever say \*"I saw a car and bus" without repeating the article. It kind of sounds as is the speaker was trying to describe some single thing named "car-and-bus" (maybe a car attached to a bus somehow?), which is of course silly.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: that could be the explanation why "I saw a blue mother and child" is fine if unlikely, "I saw a blue shirt and tie" is fine but probably means you're shopping or you'd have mentioned the person wearing them, and "I saw a blue waistcoat and hammer" doesn't really parse. To my ear, anyway. The "X and Y" needs to be an actual pairing in order to say "a blue X and Y" rather than disambiguating by saying either "a blue X and a Y" or "a blue X and a blue Y". For me, "A blue car and bus" offers no such pairing, and it's out.

Comment: Bring back hyphens, if you ask me. "I saw a blue mother-and-child", "I saw a blue shirt-and-tie", "I saw a blue wheel-and-axle". But what's a "waistcoat-and-hammer". What's a "car-and-bus"? Sometimes a construction that follows some grammatical production rule is disallowed just because the result of it doesn't exist as a concept. You can put a hammer near a waistcoat, but that still doesn't make it a waistcoat-and-hammer.

Answer (score 5):

I've read through the responses, and I see a lack of agreement of responses, so I'll speak to my experience as a native speaker with some insight into language. First, the idea that the construction is not grammatical is clearly wrong. The question of whether something is frequently said, sometimes referred to as idiomatic, and whether it violates grammar are two different things. A related example of this is ["Colorless green ideas sleep furiously"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously). Because the question of whether or not the bus is blue is vague, does not make it non-grammatical. It makes it semantically ambiguous.

Secondly, "I saw a car and a bus" can certainly be shortened to "I saw a car and bus" with an implication that the indefinite article "a" carries over to the bus meaning "I saw a pair of things: car and bus". But the caveat is that it is only an implication and therefore it is [vague](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vagueness). Vagueness in language is a feature by which the tokens of a language can have multiple senses and require disambiguation.

"I saw a blue car and bus" today to my ear as a native speaker suggests "I saw a pair of things: a blue car and blue bus", but some less competent native speakers might violate an important rule by using the sentence and not meaning that the bus was also blue. So, in a court of law, for instance, any attorney isn't going to let the vagueness stand, and would ask follow up questions to avoid confusion.

There are some rules that speakers use that it is best to be familiar with that are known collectively in the philosophy of language as obeying the [cooperative principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_principle#Maxim_of_manner_(clarity)).

**The maxim of quantity** would be violated by saying "A blue car and a blue bus" because shorter is better. Thus "A blue car and bus" doesn't waste any time. **The maxim of manner or clarity** is violated by "A blue car and bus" and so "A blue car and a blue bus" is better. So what does a speaker do when two principles intuitively clash? They rely on the [context of the conversation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_(linguistics)). Which means they're both right depending on how they play a role in part of the larger conversation. Children and jokes often playfully exploit this sort of vagueness.

Thus, both are grammatical AND idiomatic under the right situation. Unless you provide additional context, it's difficult to advise.

Comment: +1. So informative and refreshing!

Comment: I don't really think "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" speaks to "grammatical vs. idiomatic". Yes, it's grammatical, but to me it's also perfectly idiomatic. It's just not something that occurred to anyone to say, in large part because to the extent it can be understood at all, it's simply not *true* ("colorless green" being contradictory to the point that, even if ideas can have color in some figurative sense, you sort of think there'd still be no colorless green ideas to speak of). But, if that's what you meant, you'd say it that way.

Comment: @SteveJessop I offered as an example of the distinction among meaningful, idiomatic, and syntactic. It is syntactic, not literally meaningful, but idiomatic only as a reference for understanding the syntactic-semantic distinction.

Comment: That being said,  it is not idiomatic to even most native Engliah speakers, but is idiomatic as linguistic jargon. Obviously,  whether or not it is idiomatic to a speaker is a function of sophistication of knowledge. For an ELL, it's unlikely to be idiomatic.

Comment: Well yes, the trouble with an example of something that nobody has ever said, is that you just said it ;-) I suppose my understanding of "idiomatic" as meaning, "the way you would construct a sentence to have the meaning that this has", as opposed to, "an example of something that people actually have said", may be incorrect. "Sleep furiously" I have absolutely no problem with. "Colorless green" is a contradiction, but is still the idiomatic way to state such any contradictory precondition.

Comment: ... much as you might (counter-factually) say, "sane liberal people don't exist". If not for that contradiction, "green ideas sleep furiously" suggests to me that environmentalism is (in the speaker's opinion) currently on the downlow, but those entertaining such views are very unhappy about it ;-) Sorry Noam, but the supposed lack of semantics of the sentence is a lot of fuss about nothing, really. It's only "colorless" that's mysterious ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Quite the ardent defense that you're able to project some meaning onto a relatively meaningless phrase. :D You missed your calling as a poet, I suspect.

Comment: @JD: yeah, and I think the caveat that the sentence doesn't admit a *literal* meaning is quite an important one for this reason. Just the way people's imaginations work, I think, is that one can start from such an utterance and then try to figure out what strange circumstances might cause somebody to say it. To some extent that's how we understand actual difficult sentences: why might this be said? Well then that might be what it means.

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly confident in saying that your example sentence:

> "I saw a blue car and bus"

is not grammatically correct English, and also not something a native speaker would ever normally utter.*

English requires articles before nouns (except when it doesn't, but let's not dive into *that* rabbit hole right now).  And a fluent English speaker *would* insert one before "bus", unless they were either:

1. referring to some single thing named "car-and-bus", or
2. trying to use the word "bus" as something other than a singular countable common noun.**

So it's not surprising that you're getting contradictory answers on how different people understand this broken sentence, since it all depends on how they try to mentally correct it.

---

Anyway, inserting the missing article, the corrected sentence "I saw a blue car and **a** bus" strictly speaking only says that the car was blue, without implying anything about the color of the bus.  It *could* of course also be blue, but it doesn't have to be.

That said, in a suitable context, I could see it carrying a *suggestion* that the bus was blue, too.  For example, imagine a child playing a game where they have to spot as many different blue things as they can during a trip, and later being asked by their parent if they saw any, and answering:

> "Yes I did!  I saw a blue car and a bus and a mailbox and a traffic sign and flowers and a balloon and…"

The speaker certainly *could* have repeated the word "blue" before each item in the list, but they chose not to (and the parent listening to them was probably thankful for it).  But the contextual implication that this is a list of blue things is still there, even if only the first item is explicitly described as being blue.

---

*) Those are not the same thing, at least not unless you want to be an ultra-descriptivist and basically define something to be "grammatically correct" if and only if it's idiomatic for native speakers of the language to say.  While I tend to be a descriptivist myself, I wouldn't go quite *that* far: even if a grammar, to me, is essentially an attempt to formalize how speakers of a language actually communicate, I'm still willing to grant such formal descriptions an existence and validity separate from the vague and nebulous thing that they try to describe.

**) A second verb could come naturally after "and", but "bus" can't really be parsed as a verb here, since it doesn't look like a regular past tense English verb ending in "-ed" and doesn't match any common verb with an irregular past tense either.  Of course there are other possible interpretations too, like "Bus" maybe being somebody's (kind of weird) name, but those get increasingly outlandish and unlikely.

Comment: The core premise of this answer is wrong, articles _can_ be omitted due to repetition. _"English requires articles before nouns"_ is plain wrong, as evidenced by your own usage of "English", "articles" and "nouns" **in that very sentence**. _"except when it doesn't, but let's not dive into that rabbit hole right now"_ is a cop out as this is the core focus of your answer, which for some unexplained reason you willfully don't address. Then you continue with explaining that "blue" could be omitted due to repetition, somehow still willfully ignoring that the same applies to the article itself.

Comment: I'm not downvoting, but as a native speaker of linguistic competency, I'd say that it would be perfectly natural to say "blue car and bus" in certain contexts. For instance "What color vehicles did you see today?" -> "I saw a blue car and bus.", "I saw a blue car, truck, and bus." It sounds natural to my ear to omit on both. The use of other articles would be redundant, particularly in the latter example. Also, just because there is non-standard usage, you can't declare something non-grammatical. "I saw a blue car and bus" is certainly grammatical. "I ate a piece of toast and bacon"...

Comment: has exactly the same structure and is equally as sensible and it would be non-grammatical to include an article because 'bacon' is a mass noun. Articles are tricky and subtle, and often not required. "I saw a star" Ok. "I saw star". Not. "I saw the stars". Ok. "I saw stars". Ok too. "I saw the moon and star". Ok too. There's another example where it's absolutely natural to drop an article for brevity. "I saw a car and bus on the road". That works. "I washed a car and bus earlier." Yeah, I don't think your claim holds any weight.

Comment: I decided given the range of answers to share my own https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/341957/124213 and given your advanced interest in language Grice's maxim's might be of some interest to you in reasoning about language.

Comment: @J D: I wonder if there's some regional/dialect difference here. All the acceptable examples you give sound bad to me. I simply would never answer the question, "What colour vehicles did you see today?" with "I saw a blue car and bus", if the fact was I saw one blue car and one blue bus. I would edit any document going across my desk that said that. I'm in the UK, hence "color" -> "colour", and maybe this is the same. FWIW if the question was just "What vehicles did you see?" then I might say, "I saw a car, a truck, and a bus" but never "I saw a car, truck and bus".

Comment: I say "all" - that's a complete lie. I accept "I ate a piece of toast and bacon" (also I accept, with an indefinite article, "a piece of toast and some bacon"). And I accept the astronomical ones, although to me "I saw the moon and star" implies you saw something like an Islamic flag. Otherwise it couldn't be *the* star. But what I meant was, I reject all of your omitted articles in lists of vehicles :-)

Comment: For an example of the version with a verb: "I saw a blue car and wept". But to be fair, the question did say it only concerns cases where the last word has been parsed as a noun. So thankfully the questioner ruled out the "fruit flies like a banana" scenario, where it's potentially ambiguous what's a verb.

Answer (score 3):

I'm adding another answer, as all the other answers completely miss the point of this question.

OP,

### Ambiguity has no connection, at all - utterly no connection - in any way - whatsoever - to grammar.

It's that simple. End of story.

- An utterance which is perfectly grammatically correct, can be completely ambiguous.
- An utterance which has grammatical errors, can be completely ambiguous.
- An utterance which is perfectly grammatically correct, can be unambiguous.
- An utterance which has grammatical errors, can be unambiguous.

### Grammar has simply *no connection at all, in any way* to ambiguity - just as it obviously has no connection to content.

Note that similarly grammar has, obviously, no connection to *content*.

Say I said "Radio signals work by using fairy dust." If you then asked "what's wrong with that sentence grammatically" you would be completely misguided.

### Over and over on this site, questions are asked about the grammar of ambiguous sentences. This is simply misguided.

I think it's worth noting that answers which fail to immediately and conclusively point out that grammar has nothing to do with ambiguity, really confuse the OP. Unfortunately this confusion happens over and over, almost daily, on this site.

Comment: Pretty sure that's untrue. Language evolves toward an equilbrium between ease of utterance and disambiguation. Over the centuries clarity and grammar are intertwined. I can only think of a suboptimal example where [lack of] ambiguity has shaped grammar over the centuries ( *lie* / *lay*, *sit* / *set* ) but I'll think of better ones. Point being semistandard forms are more readily accepted if they don't create confusion.

Comment: I'm afraid that's surely "totally wrong", CN !!!!  Ambiguity, ambiguous sentences, are so common in English they are *ubiquitous*.  One can instantly give millions of examples (such as the first three sentences in your comment). Re your second sentence, I don't see any evidence at all, or even a general feel, that language evolves towards either of those two things. (A general observation, English, by far the most successful language in every way, there's not even a second place, celebrates, swims in, gushes over: messiness, slang and ambiguity. {Overwhelmingly so in the recent century!!})

Comment: Thanks for your remarks. "...so common in English." That doesn't directly address the claim I've made. No one is suggesting any language is completely free of ambiguity, rather that avoidance of ambiguity [imperfectly] shapes development over time. Cheers.

Comment: “I am going to Lowe’s, and I will be there at eight” is grammatically correct but entirely ambiguous. Lowe’s food (a grocery chain) or Lowe’s Home Improvement? 8:00 or 20:00? Grammar and ambiguity are separate concepts. The OP has provided another example in the original question.

Comment: I don’t see how this answers the question.

Comment: OK ... "What is the outcome [of the ambiguity] of any and every sentence in the following sentence format when the rules of English grammar is applied upon them"  Answer, no connection in any way, at all, between ambiguity and grammar.

Comment: @CarstenS It states that the question has no answer, which is a valid kind of answer.

Comment: Note that the possibility of all four quadrants does not imply "utterly no connection". There are tall adults, tall children, short adults and short children. It does not follow that your height has *utterly* no connection to whether you're a child or an adult. Pretty much everybody averages shorter as a child than they later do as an adult ;-) Nevertheless, you are correct that the answer to this question does not lie in correctly solving the grammar of their sentence template :-)

Comment: ... because, as you say, it's wrong to think that every grammatical sentence is unambiguous. Also because it's wrong to think that every fixed format for a sentence has a fixed interpretation, even once you've fixed what all the parts of speech will be.

Comment: Anyway the answer to the question is, "there is no outcome of any and every sentence". Plain examples: "I saw a red shirt and tie" - both are definitely red; "This bin forbids hot ashes and liquids" - applying common sense, liquids of any temperature are forbidden, but it's at best ambiguous and *certainly* it's not definite that cold liquids aren't forbidden.

Answer (score 0):

On its own, it does not imply that the bus is blue. But it probably is, because if the colour of the bus isn't blue you would probably mention that fact.

But in natural contexts, the listener might infer or understand that the bus was also blue. You would need to know why the person was talking about cars and buses; what question were they answering?

> What colours of vehicles did you see today?
>
> I saw a blue car and bus.

In this conversation (about colour) I'd infer that the bus was also blue.

On the other hand, suppose I said "I ate spicy chicken and chips".  I'd probably assume that "spicy" only applies to the chicken.

In particular cases, you would assume that the adjective applies to both, or only to one. But you can't generalise this to a universal rule.

Comment: *I saw a blue car and bus* might be an odd thing to say, but syntactically and semantically, it's no different to *I have a younger brother and sister* - which unquestionably implies the adjective attaches to both nouns by default.

Comment: I agree that it matches "I have a younger brother and sister" and normally one would infer that the sister was younger. But I don't think that is given.  What about "a younger brother, and sister" or "a younger brother, and a sister"  ? There are doubtless other contexts in which "a {adjective} {noun} and {noun}" would clearly not apply the adjective to the second noun. In general, more context is needed.

Comment: You're introducing a comma, which obviously changes the meaning (the *purpose* of the comma being to distance the second noun from the first, so the adjective *doesn't* "carry forward"). The comma is an even stronger "separator" than repeating the article. But learners need to get their heads around the fact that we specify the unmodified noun first, when the adjective doesn't apply to both nouns. Then they wouldn't have to pore over these misleading artificial examples, anyway.

Comment: I just had some spicy chicken and chips.   Were the chips spicy?

Comment: Pragmatics and idiomatically established collocations come into play there. This doesn't alter the fact that the *default* interpretation of *adj noun and noun* is *adj noun and adj noun*, no matter how many counterexamples you produce. Learners need to learn defaults - it's not helpful to give them the impression there aren't even any *principles* (let along *rules*) just because there are always exceptions.

Comment: Me, I had cold chicken and chips. Were my chips cold?

Comment: Yes, they were spicy. If you had had "some spicy chicken and *some* chips," then they wouldn't be. Not sure about @FumbleFingers chips, though. They used a proper zero article.

Comment: But actually they weren't spicy.  So by blindly following a rule you have come to the wrong conclusion.  And this really is the point.  I don't think the OP is really asking about cars and buses; they are asking if there is a universal rule that can apply in all contexts, and I don't believe that there is.

Comment: @JamesK This is different. It's grammatical to say "some" once and for it to apply to "spicy chicken" and "chips". So your phrase is OK and does not imply that the chips are spicy. "A" is different because it can only apply to a singular count noun phrase.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that the determiner provides context by which you can infer if the adjective applies to both nouns or not....

Comment: Unquestionably! The very first point I made in my answer was that repetition of the article in my example *I have a younger brother and **a** sister* (and/or a ***comma before 'and'***) both tend to dissociate the two nps, thereby overriding the default principle that a leading adjective would by default normally apply to *both* nouns.

Comment: ... @RosieF I'm not 100% convinced that leading ***some*** makes any difference (both ***some*** and ***spicy*** could in principle "ripple through" from ***chicken*** in James's example; nothing is really "fixed" there). But whereas *my* chips could have been hot, warm, or cold, if I'd said *I had cold chicken and some chips* there would be no tendency *whatsoever* to extend the scope of ***cold*** to the chips (***some*** is the determiner for a plural np, same as ***a / an*** before a singular np prevents the adjective from applying to that second np).

Comment: JamesK Yes indeed. I should acknowledge that a noun phrase can be two nouns joined by "and", such as "horse and carriage". There, one determiner and one adjective can apply to that whole noun phrase. But "car" and "bus" don't go together like that. So the OP's "a blue car and bus" is ungrammatical because "bus" lacks a determiner as @IlmariKaronen [said](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/341883).

Comment: I do not agree that there is no rule to decide the precedence relationship between nouns & conjunctions & determiners & adjectives. The rules of English grammar is crystal clear & black & white (i.e there are no grey areas). I have so many evidences to prove that. But, it will take a long time to reveal those evidences in the comment section. If you disagree with me, then let us just agree to disagree and leave it at that stage. @FumbleFingers, don't force me to agree to your point. You telling the same thing over and over again is getting viral, while my question still remaining unanswered.

Comment: And also people have forgotten the original primary question and have started to discuss impertinent things, while my question still remaining unanswered. I think I have made my question clear by repeating it many times (because you asked for it) in different ways and words.

Comment: "The rules of English grammar is crystal clear & black & white (i.e there are no grey areas)." is not correct; in fact, the opposite is true: Generally the only rule in English without exceptions is that all English rules have exceptions.

Comment: @Stechavy: I don't understand why you asked the querstion in the first place if you claim to know "the rules" of English better than native Anglophones. You're completely mistaken on this specific point though. James might be overstating the case for there being ***no*** "rule", but obviously there are so many perfectly valid examples of utterances that don't observe the ***general principle*** that no-one could sensibly claim there's an actual rule here. It really is just a tendency, and there are probably identifiable subcategories of contexts where it *doesn't* apply.

Comment: @Stechavy: the reason you're getting this repetition is that, to English speakers, you have in effect asked, "what is the sale price of any and every car in the English-speaking world". The fact is, we don't have any rule in English that determines the price of every car. Different cars have different prices. Sorry. It's possible that you've seen an English grammar book that claims to be a complete and unambiguous prescriptive statement of English grammar. But if so then that book has over-claimed. People are messy. Granted, a price is a number whereas "is the bus blue" is yes/no, but still.

Comment: @JamesK Hi! I upvoted your good answer! Someone downvoted it. The score of that good answer was - 1.Now is 0.Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the sentence suggests to me that the car and the bus are a set in some way. Otherwise I would expect to expand it to “I saw a blue car and I saw bus”, which makes no sense. As a blue set, both the car and the bus would be blue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a non-English speaker who has immersed himself in this language for over 20 years.
To me, this sentence should read as: I saw a blue car and a bus. And, with or without "a", I would understand the person saw a blue car, but not necessarily a [blue] bus; the bus can come in any color.
And if an officer asked me what I saw, I'd say I saw a car and a bus, which were both blue.

Comment: Unfortunately (for English) this is "completely wrong" !  Heh!  It would be totally commonplace that the sentence form means both A and B are blue; you can trivially give a zillion examples. ("I saw a French mother and child.")  *Grammar* is totally, completely, wholly uninvolved here.  Sure, the sentence (which is utterly correct grammatically) "I saw a blue sky and bricks" is strange, but so what?

Comment: Oh, I see. You mean the sentence is correct and the bus can be blue too? A matter of ellipsis? [I'm not claiming, I'm just asking to learn]