# In the sentence "a wonderful puppet that would know how to dance and fight and leap like an acrobat" which word(s) refer to acrobat?

Tags: meaning

Here is a part of the Pinocchio story that I found ambiguous,

> He decided to make himself a wooden puppet - a wonderful puppet that would know how to dance and fight and leap like an acrobat.

I'd like to know which word(s) refer to acrobat. Longman defines acrobat as the following,

> Someone who entertains people by doing difficult physical actions such as walking on their hands or balancing on a high rope, especially at a circus.

So I think only the last word (leap) refers to acrobat. Am I right?

Comment: Connected by *and"  I'd say that all of the verbs are acrobatical. Dancing with leaps can be acrobatic, and I've seen acrobats fling each other around while gripping each other at the forearm and it bore some resemblance to fighting.

Comment: *Syntactically*, the text is ambiguous. Logicsally, it's unlikely *like an acrobat* would apply to *fight and leap* but not *dance*, but syntactically (if the specific words made more sense with that parsing) even that would be possible. But even discounting *that* possibility, at the level of syntax, it could refer to just the final verb *leap*, OR to all three (but the *spoken* versions of those two possibilities would be different).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> He decided to make himself a wooden puppet - a wonderful puppet that would know how to dance and fight and leap like an acrobat.

From context, *acrobat* refers to *leap*, based on what an acrobat usually does.  Syntactically, however, it could refer also to *dance* and *fight*.

A comma would help; we place it before the last *and*:

> He decided to make himself a wooden puppet - a wonderful puppet that would know how to dance and fight[,] and leap like an acrobat.

Alternatively, we shift to the front the verb to be modified and its preposition phrase:

> He decided to make himself a wooden puppet - a wonderful puppet that would know how to **leap like an acrobat** and dance and fight.

In a construction with a post-modifier  modifying just one of the terms, we should place at the front that modifier and the term.  We do the reverse for constructions with pre-modifiers.

Please see [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/341834/does-i-saw-a-blue-car-and-bus-mean-blue-bus-or-any-coloured-bus#341839) too.

Comment: Good answer. Also, this sentence would lose its ambiguity when spoken aloud.